# Cannot find a matrix sign (A+) anywhere

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, operator-algebras, matrix-calculus

I have a task on Linear Algebra and in it for a matrix "A" I have to find a matrix, which is denoted as "A+" ("+" is placed higher, like the degree, not like a usual plus and how I've wrote).

Please, tell me, if you know, what matrix is this and what operation it does make.

Comment: It could be the transpose, or it could be the conjugate transpose.  The best person to ask is the person who gave you the task.

Comment: In addition to the possibilities in the previous comment, the transpose $A^T$ and the adjoint $A^\dagger$, it could also be the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse $A^+$.

Comment: @matthew-leingang thanks for the answer, that person does not answer now,

I think that it's not a transpose, 'cause it's denoted with "T" in the task.

Comment: @quasicoherent thanks for the answer, I've checked now and think that it's the last variant (and it's also visually the most similar)

Comment: Or perhaps $A^+ = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$, the symmetric part of $A$; we also have $A^- = \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$, the skew-symmetric part.  I have seen both usages.

Comment: If this is for a course and you're using a textbook, can you mention what textbook it is?

Comment: @j-m-is-not-a-mathematician, This is not from a book, it's just a task: "For a matrix A = {1, 0, 3; -2, 3, 0} find A+" ("A+" straightly looks like the last variant from Quasicoherent answer).